# FragmentStatePagerAdapter cannot update viewpager's view

Tags: android

I use FragmentStatePagerAdapter to manage my ViewPager. I have overwritten "getItemPosition" function. Here is my code:

```
mViewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) { 
            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                Crime c = mCrimes.get(position);
                return CrimeFragment.newInstance(c.getmId());
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return mCrimes.size(); 
            }
            @Override
            public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
                return POSITION_NONE;
            }
        });
```

But the problem is that when I delete the first fragment, the last fragment will be deleted, but others work well. I don't know why.

Comment: `getItemPosition` is called when the host view is attempting to determine if an item's position has changed. You are always returning `POSITION_NONE`

Comment: So how can I change my code?

Comment: why did you override `getItemPosition` in first place?

Comment: I just searched it on the Internet and it told me to